# puppet user module not updating /etc/group on servers

Tags: linux, debian, puppet

i am using the puppet user module, its able to create the users and add them to the correct group, however i have moved one user to another group and puppet moved the user to that group on the remote server, but did not remove the user from the previous group?

```
define account ($ensure = present, $password = '!!', $groups = [], $shell = '/bin/bash', $dotfile = false, $key = false) {
    $username = $name
    # Default user settings
    user { "$username":
        ensure     => $ensure,
        gid        => $username,
        password   => $password,
        groups     => $groups,
        comment    => ",,,",
        home       => "/home/$username",
        shell      => $shell,
        allowdupe  => false,
        managehome => true,
    }

    # Default group settings
    group { "$username":
        ensure    => $ensure,
        allowdupe => false,
    }

    # Ordering of dependencies, just in case
    case $ensure {
        present: {
                User <| title == "$username" |> {
                           require =>  Group["$username"]
                }
        }
        absent: { Group <| title == "$username" |> { require => User["$username"] } }
    }

    file { "/home/${username}":
        ensure  => $ensure ? {
                present => directory,
                absent  => absent,
                },
        owner   => $username,
        group   => $username,
        mode    => 644,
        require   => User["${username}"],
   }

   file { "/home/${username}/.ssh":
        ensure  => directory,
        owner   => $username,
        group   => $username,
        mode    => 700,
        require => File["/home/${username}"],
   }

   if ($key != false) {
     ssh_authorized_key { "${name}_key":
       key => $key,
       type => "ssh-rsa",
       user => $name,
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by-design to prevent removing users from system groups.

You can work around that by using the membership => inclusive attribute.

More info: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/7241